# android set Text changing style due a method with getResources

Tags: java, android

I want an app to calculate a deceleration and I want to display it in a TextView. However, if this deceleration is out of range, I want to change the style of the TextView in my MainActivity.java (I use Android Studio 1.5.1)

Here is my style.xml

```xml
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="outOfRange" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- When the deceleration is out of range, it changes its style -->
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#f44336</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And my display method:

```
 /**
 * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
 * @param calculDes is the deceleration result calculated
 */
private void displayDes1(double calculDes) {

    boolean isInRnage = true;

    if (calculDes > -0.3 || calculDes < -1.25 ){
        isInRnage = false;
    }

    //Create an object DecimalFormat with the wished pattern ("#.##")
    DecimalFormat formaDecimals = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    //transform deceleration to String with 2 decimals
    String desaccTextDecimals = formaDecimals.format(calculDes);


    TextView desacceleracioTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desacceleracio1);

    if (!isInRnage){

        desacceleracioTextView.getResources().getIdentifier("outOfRange","style", getPackageName());
        desacceleracioTextView.setText(desaccTextDecimals);


    }else {
        //The result is shown in a TextView object
        desacceleracioTextView.setText(desaccTextDecimals);
    }
}
```

My problem is in here :

```
    if (!isInRnage){
        desacceleracioTextView.getResources().getIdentifier("outOfRange","style", getPackageName());
        desacceleracioTextView.setText(desaccTextDecimals);
    }
```

As I said before, I would like to setText with a changing style if the deceleration is out of range.

Comment: does MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the setTextAppearance method on your TextView to change the style.

```
   if (!isInRnage){
    desacceleracioTextView.setTextAppearance(R.style.outOfRange);
    desacceleracioTextView.setText(desaccTextDecimals);
}
```

Please note there is the setTextAppearance method that takes both a context and a style has been deprecated as of API level 23, so I am using the newer version here, which just takes the style resource ID.  You may need to update the targetSdkVersion in your build.gradle.

If you just want to use the old setTextAppearance method do this:

```
 if (!isInRnage){
        desacceleracioTextView.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.outOfRange);
        desacceleracioTextView.setText(desaccTextDecimals);
    }
```

For more info on both the old and new setTextAppearance methods, see the documentation on TextView here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextAppearance(int)

Also I left the typo in your boolean the way it is, but you might want to fix that.

Comment: Thanks a lot joshgoldeneagle!! As you said, the newest version of setTextAperance is for API level 23. So, I use the old one. And it's exactly whatr I needed!